# How to statically compile modules in Apache 2.2.17 for Win32

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

is it possibile to statically compile modules in apache.exe?

On both linux and mac side I was able to build an apache exec (httpd) stand alone that contains both all deps (apr, apr-util, pcre) and the modules that I needed, but in Windows I was only able to build an apache.exe stand alone (that cointains only apr.dll, apr-util.dll and other deps) without modules. So for example, I cannot be able to use the Order directive in httpd.conf file because the needed module is not included in apache.exe.

I modify a lot of mak files included the httpd.mak file in order to build the apache.exe using link.exe in this way:

```
link.exe Release\main.obj \ 
Release\httpd.res \ 
srclib\apr\Release\libapr.lib \ 
srclib\pcre\Release\pcre.lib \ 
srclib\apr-iconv\Release\libapriconv.lib \ 
Release\my_modules.lib \ 
Release\libhttpd.lib
```

every .lib file has all the obj files built statically with lib.exe

Building in this way the "my_modules.lib" seems to be ignored and all the obj module files were not included in the apache.exe (for example mod_authn_file.obj, mod_expires, mod_actions and so on...).

If I add obj files explicitally during build in this way:

```
link.exe Release\main.obj \ 
Release\httpd.res \ 
srclib\apr\Release\libapr.lib \ 
srclib\pcre\Release\pcre.lib \ 
srclib\apr-iconv\Release\libapriconv.lib \ 
Release\libhttpd.lib \ 
modules\Release\mod_authn_file.obj \ 
modules\Release\mod_expires.obj \ 
modules\Release\mod_actions.obj \ 
...... (other object modules)
```

the size of apache.exe grow but if I use the command apache.exe -M to see Loaded Modules, I find only:

```
core_module (static) 
win32_module (static) 
mpm_winnt_module (static) 
http:module (static) 
so_module (static)
```

[that are all modules that aren't included in my_modules.lib]

Using Dependency Walker I can see all the modules in the apache.exe:

```
actions_module
alias_module
_ap_get_server_built@0
auth_basic_module
authn_default_module
authn_file_module
authz_default_module
authz_groupfile_module
authz_host_module
authz_user_module
cgi_module
dir_module
expires_module
filter_module
http_module
log_config_module
mime_module
mpm_winnt_module
setenvif_module
so_module
status_module
version_module
win32_module
```

It seems that the modules were linked but they were not enabled...

I hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it...

I modified modules.c file in os/win32/ folder in this way:

```
#undef AP_DECLARE_EXPORT
#define AP_DECLARE_STATIC

#define CORE_PRIVATE
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"

extern module core_module;
extern module win32_module;
extern module mpm_winnt_module;
extern module http_module;
extern module so_module;
extern module authn_file_module;
extern module authn_default_module;
extern module authz_host_module;
extern module authz_groupfile_module;
extern module authz_user_module;
extern module authz_default_module;
extern module auth_basic_module;
extern module filter_module;
extern module deflate_module;
extern module log_config_module;
extern module expires_module;
extern module setenvif_module;
extern module version_module;
extern module ssl_module;
extern module mime_module;
extern module status_module;
extern module cgi_module;
extern module dir_module;
extern module actions_module;
extern module alias_module;

AP_DECLARE_DATA module *ap_prelinked_modules[] = {
  &core_module,
  &win32_module,
  &mpm_winnt_module,
  &http_module,
  &so_module,
  &authn_file_module,
  &authn_default_module,
  &authz_host_module,
  &authz_groupfile_module,
  &authz_user_module,
  &authz_default_module,
  &auth_basic_module,
  &filter_module,
  &deflate_module,
  &log_config_module,
  &expires_module,
  &setenvif_module,
  &version_module,
  &ssl_module,
  &mime_module,
  &status_module,
  &cgi_module,
  &dir_module,
  &actions_module,
  &alias_module,
  NULL
};

ap_module_symbol_t ap_prelinked_module_symbols[] = {
  {"core_module", &core_module},
  {"win32_module", &win32_module},
  {"mpm_winnt_module", &mpm_winnt_module},
  {"http_module", &http_module},
  {"so_module", &so_module},
  {"authn_file_module", &authn_file_module},
  {"authn_default_module", &authn_default_module},
  {"authz_host_module", &authz_host_module},
  {"authz_groupfile_module", &authz_groupfile_module},
  {"authz_user_module", &authz_user_module},
  {"authz_default_module", &authz_default_module},
  {"auth_basic_module", &auth_basic_module},
  {"filter_module", &filter_module},
  {"deflate_module", &deflate_module},
  {"log_config_module", &log_config_module},
  {"expires_module", &expires_module},
  {"setenvif_module", &setenvif_module},
  {"version_module", &version_module},
  {"ssl_module", &ssl_module},
  {"mime_module", &mime_module},
  {"status_module", &status_module},
  {"cgi_module", &cgi_module},
  {"dir_module", &dir_module},
  {"actions_module", &actions_module},
  {"alias_module", &alias_module},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

AP_DECLARE_DATA module *ap_preloaded_modules[] = {
  &core_module,
  &win32_module,
  &mpm_winnt_module,
  &http_module,
  &so_module,
  &authn_file_module,
  &authn_default_module,
  &authz_host_module,
  &authz_groupfile_module,
  &authz_user_module,
  &authz_default_module,
  &auth_basic_module,
  &filter_module,
  &deflate_module,
  &log_config_module,
  &expires_module,
  &setenvif_module,
  &version_module,
  &ssl_module,
  &mime_module,
  &status_module,
  &cgi_module,
  &dir_module,
  &actions_module,
  &alias_module,
  NULL
};
```

then I recompile the modules.obj file with this command:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sessa\Desktop\httpd-2.2.17-win32-src\httpd-2.2.17_21>
cl.exe /nologo /MT /W3 /Zi /O2 /Oy- /I "./srclib/pcre" /I "./include" /I "./srclib/apr/include" /I "./srclib/apr-util/include" /I "./server/mpm/winnt" /I "./modules/http" /I "./modules/proxy" /I "./modules/mappers" /I "./server" /I"./modules/generators" /I "./modules/filters" /D "NDEBUG" /D "WIN32" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "APR_DECLARE_STATIC" /D "AP_DECLARE_STATIC" /D "API_DECLARE_STATIC" /D"APU_DECLARE_STATIC" /D "PCRE_STATIC" /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\modules_sessa" /FD /c ./os/win32/modules.c
```

then I rebuild apache.exe and execute apache.exe -M:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 win32_module (static)
 mpm_winnt_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 authn_default_module (static)
 authz_host_module (static)
 authz_groupfile_module (static)
 authz_user_module (static)
 authz_default_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (static)
 filter_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 expires_module (static)
 setenvif_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 deflate_module (static)
 ssl_module (static)
 mime_module (static)
 status_module (static)
 cgi_module (static)
 dir_module (static)
 actions_module (static)
 alias_module (static)
Syntax OK
```

so in this way I have compiled an apache 2.2.17 statically for win32!